# Writing permutation as a product of disjoint cycles.

Tags: combinatorics

Decompose $(123)(423) (54)$ a product of disjoint cycles and write it as a product of transpositions.

Attempt:

We have $(123) (423) (54)$

$5\to4\to2\to3$

$4\to5$

$3\to4$

$2\to3\to1$

$1\to2$

Comment: So you've proved it's $(534)(21)$. Can't you write $(543)$ as a product of transpositions?

Comment: That's correct. There remains to write the disjoint cycles.

Comment: Is product of disjoint cycles (12)(345)?

Comment: @Mians Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

For the writing as a product of transpositions, it is enough to know how to write a cycle as a product of transpositions. Here is how on an example: consider, say,  the cycle $(1453)$:

- multiplying on the left by the transposition $(14)$, we get
  $$(14)(1453)=(345).$$
- next multiply (still on the left) by $(34)$:
  $$(34)(345)=(45),$$
  so $\;(34)(14)(1453)=(45)$,and therefore
  $$\color{red}{(1453)}=(14)(34)\bigl[(34)(14)(1453)\bigr]=\color{red}{(14)(34)(45)}.$$